# What is this operator "?." in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, operators

i work with flutter framework
this part of the code use a operation "?." but idont understand

```
 if (state is WeatherLoaded) {
          final weather = state.weather;
          final themeBloc = BlocProvider.of<ThemeBloc>(context);
          themeBloc.dispatch(WeatherChanged(condition: weather.condition));

          _refreshCompleter?.complete();
          _refreshCompleter = Completer();
```

all code [this](https://gist.github.com/felangel/bed1d113dc3c721394dbc58eee4cd494#file-weather-dart) link

Comment: It would help people to address your issue it you formulated a direct question. Explain a little more what is it that you do not understand, or formulate a What or Why question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to demonstrate this is a simple example.
I have an object `SomeObject` with one method `username`.

I have made 2 instances of it:

- `aeonObject` which is not `null`
- `someOtherObject` which is `null`

```dart
class SomeObject {
  String username() => "aeon";
}

void main() {
  final aeonObject = SomeObject();
  print(aeonObject.username());

  SomeObject someOtherObject;
  print(someOtherObject.username());
}
```

If I execute this snippet you'll see the following output.
The program will crash because we tried to execute a method on a `null` reference.

> dart lib/main.dart
>   lib/main.dart: Warning: Interpreting this as package URI, 'package:sample/main.dart'.
>
> aeon
>
> Unhandled exception:
>   NoSuchMethodError: The method 'username' was called on null.
>
> Receiver: null
>   Tried calling: username()

However if I call the `print` statement with the `?.` aka `Conditional member access operator`.

```dart
print(someOtherObject?.username());
```

We instead get.

> null

Comment: @tm why they give false.

print("check ${someOtherObject?.username() == "aeon"}"); // false

Comment: Since null != "aeon"

Answer (score 1):

Check this link: [Language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators)

> ?.
>
> Conditional member access
>
> Like ., but the leftmost operand can be null; example: foo?.bar
>   selects property bar from expression foo unless foo is null (in which
>   case the value of foo?.bar is null)